# C: Effective Macro Usage

Tags: c, macros

```
#ifndef MACROS_NULLCHECK_H_
#define MACROS_NULLCHECK_H_

#include <assert.h>

#define NULLCHECK(x) assert(x != (void *) 0);

#endif
```

If I used the above style as a template for declaring Macros, what provisos would you have?

Comment: disregarding your question for a moment: the macro `NULLCHECK()` is useless: pointers are scalar types and therefore can be used in boolean contexts; `NULLCHECK(foo)` does exactly the same thing as `assert(foo)`

Comment: @Christoph True, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0/1296865 for more.

Comment: @Christoph: I disagree: Assertions should be Overt. If the assertion is actually invoked then a more overt message will be displayed. ie: `"Assertion violation: file exe.c, line $: (foo) != (void *) 0"` vs. `"Assertion violation: file exe.c, line $: (foo)"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- put parenthesis around the argument (it prevents problems when passing expressions)
- don't put ; at the end (the use will be more natural)

  #define NULLCHECK(x)  assert((x) != (void*)0)

Comment: @AProgrammer: Point #2 clicks with my way of thinking too, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3):

One change I might make would be to comment the closing `#endif`:

```
#endif  // MACROS_NULLCHECK_H_
```

It makes it easier to understand what that `#endif` is doing there when the file gets longer than a screen.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you should always put macro arguments in brackets in the expansion, i.e. in your case

```
assert((x) != (void*) 0)
```

This is because if you don't then any expressions (rather than simple variables) which you pass in may mess up the variable expansion.

I would also suggest that you DON'T put the semicolon at the end of the macro definition, so that you have to call it like

```
NULLCHECK(pSomething);
```

which just looks more C-like & consistent with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Some good macro practices from the [CERT C Secure Coding Wiki](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/01.+Preprocessor+%28PRE%29):

> PRE00-C. Prefer inline or static functions to function-like macros
>   PRE01-C. Use parentheses within macros around parameter names
>   PRE02-C. Macro replacement lists should be parenthesized
>   PRE03-C. Prefer typedefs to defines for encoding types
>   PRE10-C. Wrap multi-statement macros in a do-while loop
>   PRE11-C. Do not conclude a single statement macro definition with a semicolon
>   PRE31-C. Never invoke an unsafe macro with arguments containing assignment, increment, decrement, volatile access, or function call
>   PRE32-C. Do not use preprocessor directives inside macro arguments

Answer (score 0):

Looks good.  It's a pattern I use a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce the `;` , use

```
#define NULLCHECK(x) do { assert((X)); } while (0)
```

Comment: The do-while idiom is good when needed; the example is not compelling.