# WIndows System Programming use of standard C library

Tags: c, debugging, winapi

I'm reading Johnson M. Hart Windows System programming. He has a method that makes use of the **va_start** standard c method. In the below sample can someone explain why the **Handle hOut** is being passed to **va_start**?

```
BOOL PrintStrings (HANDLE hOut, ...)

/* Write the messages to the output handle. Frequently hOut
    will be standard out or error, but this is not required.
    Use WriteConsole (to handle Unicode) first, as the
    output will normally be the console. If that fails, use WriteFile.

    hOut:   Handle for output file. 
    ... :   Variable argument list containing TCHAR strings.
        The list must be terminated with NULL. */
{
    DWORD msgLen, count;
    LPCTSTR pMsg;
    va_list pMsgList;   /* Current message string. */
    va_start (pMsgList, hOut);  /* Start processing msgs. */
    while ((pMsg = va_arg (pMsgList, LPCTSTR)) != NULL) {
        msgLen = lstrlen (pMsg);
        if (!WriteConsole (hOut, pMsg, msgLen, &count, NULL)
                && !WriteFile (hOut, pMsg, msgLen * sizeof (TCHAR), &count, NULL)) {
            va_end (pMsgList);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    va_end (pMsgList);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: void va_start (va_list ap, paramN);
Initialize a variable argument list
Initializes ap to retrieve the additional arguments after parameter paramN.

Comment: Because the C standard requires it: the second argument to [`va_start`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start) must be the last named parameter of the function.

Comment: @Kninnug could another value be used instead of the HANDLE?

Comment: The `...` in the function signature means that the function can accept any number of arguments following `hOut`, and `va_start` and `va_arg` are how the function is able to access those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`va_start` is a macro that pulls of variadic parameters. It works by being given the parameter immediately before the first variadic parameter. The point is that `va_start` needs to know where the variadic parameters can be found. They are found immediately after the last named parameters. Hence the use of `hOut`.

Some details on how variadic parameters are typically implemented:

- [How are variable arguments implemented in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371450/how-are-variable-arguments-implemented-in-gcc)
- http://blog.aaronballman.com/2012/06/how-variable-argument-lists-work-in-c/

Comment: can you please expound a little on this statement "va_start is a macro that pulls of variadic parameters"? I very new to C and seeking some insight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure that dupe really explains what varargs are which seems to be the OP's problem.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The question can only really be interpreted as though asker already knows what varargs are.

Comment: I understand variadics. Its just unclear why the HANDLE is used.

Comment: Did you read the dupe question?

Comment: yes.. thanks for the feedback

Comment: So it's all clear now, and I can delete this?

Comment: don't delete the answer please...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan David after your explanation and running a sample under the debugger this makes sense. Thanks for the feedback and link...