# Couldn't implement function with variable arguments

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I was trying to implement function with variable arguments but was getting garbage values as output.I have referred this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371450/how-are-variable-arguments-implemented-in-gcc) before trying to implement on my own.Could anyone help me out with this code as I am unable to understand what's wrong in this code.

```
/* va_arg example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
int FindMax (int n, ...)
{
    int i,val,largest,*p;
    p=&n;
    p+=sizeof(int);
    largest=*p;
    for (i=1;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        p+=sizeof(int);
        val=*p;
        largest=(largest>val)?largest:val;
    }
    return largest;
}
int main ()
{
    int m;
    m= FindMax (7,702,422,631,834,892,104,772);
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use an array of int (int[] numbers).

Comment: Don't **ever** attempt to access the stack yourself! That's what [`stdarg.h`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) is for. There might be platforms where your naive implementation happens to work, but that would be out of pure luck.

Comment: Yeah,@Rui Silva but I was trying to implement function with variable arguments.

Comment: What is your platform/compiler/IDE etc.?

Comment: Use `malloc` to allocate memory to pointers. `p+=sizeof(int)` seems weird

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm)

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise in order to understand how things work under the hood? Or is this for real world usage?

Comment: @Michael Walz I was compiling it on Gcc.

Comment: You seem to know about `va_arg`, so what did your find out? What does your C book say how to access variadic arguments? If it is older, get a new one! ABIs have changed a lot the last 10-20 years! Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access locations on the stack directly where you *assume* to find your arguments. Calling conventions are machine- and sometimes compiler-specific and an implementation detail you **can never rely on**, so probably your arguments are not found on the stack where you assume they are. In terms of C, your code just invokes **undefined behavior**

Solution: use `stdarg.h` for accessing the arguments, that's what it's there for.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdarg.h>

int FindMax (int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int i,val,largest;

    va_start(ap, n); // <- ap is the argument pointer, this initializes it
                     //    based on the last non-variadic argument.

    largest=0;
    while (n--)
    {
        val = va_arg(ap, int); // <- fetch argument and advance pointer
        largest=(largest>val)?largest:val;
    }
    va_end(ap); // done with argument pointer

    return largest;
}
int main ()
{
    int m;
    m= FindMax (7,702,422,631,834,892,104,772);
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Felix Palmen but I have another doubt , if I wanted to access an element at some index 'i' do I need to traverse from the first element using va_arg (or need to store it in an array)or can you suggest any other method to access the va_list.

Comment: @RaviTejaNamballa Yes, that's the only thing the C standard specifies...

Comment: `int main ()` is an obsolecence signature. Use prototype-style declarators!

Comment: @Olaf it's acceptable and I won't change more in OPs code than absolutely necessary to solve the problem ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Sorry, but that's a lame excuse. Read the standard. It is subject to be removed from the standard (I'm aware about the notorious slowness of the commitee, though). Why stick to ancient coding styles?

Comment: @Olaf *supposed to* is not relevant here. Let's just focus on the question and the solution ...

Comment: Answers should also enhance code quality. That's one of the missions of this site.

Comment: @Olaf downvote if you like, I will keep my answers on point and I don't see any "bad quality" with this.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without stdarg.h?

Comment: @RaviTejaNamballa not according to C. Don't you understand this response? The point is, there are a LOT of different calling conventions, your arguments could even reside in processor registers (so you have no way to access them from C, only using assembly code)

Comment: @RaviTejaNamballa of course, you could use your own code for **one specific machine and compiler** and given this machine really has all the arguments on the stack, it could even work without assembly. It's just not a "C program" any more (contains behavior that's *undefined* according to the C standard)

Comment: @RaviTejaNamballa: The actual question is: **Why** don't you want to use `stdarg.h`? This is one of the headers _any_ C implementation has to provide, there is no point in not using it!

Comment: @Olaf : Well I am just a beginner started learning C recently and I was trying to understand how these functions are working.I got a good explanation from Felix Palmen .I will use stdarg.h as you mentioned.Thank You.