# Use of printf in C language

Tags: c, printf

As we know there is no function overloading in C language. But when we use `printf()` we supply any no of arguments to it. How is this happening?

We pass a `char` or `float` or `int` or any other datatype variable in it. (the no of times we pass these variable of different datatype can also vary). How is this working?

Also in case of string while using `%s` we pass the address of string's first character i.e only the name of string, but in other data-types we only pass the variable itself.
How is this possible even if C does not support function overloading?

Comment: duplicates: [How can printf function can take variable parameters in number while output them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23103875/995714), [How are variadic variables represented on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63056235/995714), https://stackoverflow.com/q/12371450/995714

Answer (score 1):

because the arguments to a function are just pushes onto the stack.  function signatures are useful for compilers but compilers can ignore them and the running function can just keep fetching values from the stack until they find a null (like c-style strings)

I don't know for a fact that that's how it works (I suppose it's compiler dependent) but it's a rough guess

Comment: `arguments to a function are just pushes onto the stack` not true. For example the x86-64 System V ABI passes the first 6 arguments to variadic functions in registers

Comment: Other systems like small 8-bit MCUs use static shared locations for parameters and locals with separate life times.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I assumed a particular context which may or may not be applicable