# Variadic function last parameter type

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions, undefined-behavior, type-promotion

I had this question while reading C++ Standard, but it basically just references C Standard, so I guess this question applies to both languages.

From [[cstdarg.syn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdarg.syn#header:%3ccstdarg%3e)

> If the parameter parmN is of a reference type, or of a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined.

I dont understand the rule about "compatible" types. Compatible types are pretty much the same types in C, so what does this rule means exactly? `parmN` cant be `float`, `bool`, `char`, `short`?

```
int add_nums(short count, ...) 
{
    int result = 0;
    std::va_list args;
    va_start(args, count); // undefined behavior ?
    for (short i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

Also, what is the reasoning behind this rule? I get how `parmN` cant be reference, but I dont see how its type is related to types of variadic arguments.

Comment: If you can, basically forget this and use variadic templates, which are type safe.

Comment: Sorry for the knee-jerk reaction to the C tag with the C++ code. This is a reasonable place to use both tags.

Comment: If you want to write this in C++, you do it like `auto add_nums(auto... vals) { return (vals + ...); }`

Comment: *I get how parmN cant be reference* -- really?  Can you explain it to me?  I mean, I'm sure there's a rationale, but it's not clear to me what that would be.

Comment: @John Bollinger, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371450/how-are-variable-arguments-implemented-in-gcc); from what I understand, in most implementations, `va_start` takes address of `paramN` and uses it to get the next arg. References are not required to have address in C++ [dcl.ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#4), and if we just take an address of a ref we just get address of the referenced object, so we cant use it in  `va_start` like that

Comment: @lorro yep you are right, but for some reason i just like reading the standard, finding this things no one actually use, and thinking why are they made that way

Comment: Looks like a bug in the C++ standard to me. There is no notion of compatible types in C++. What types are compatible in C is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The rule regarding types has to do with promotion of arguments.

For variadic arguments, passed arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double` and integer arguments with a type smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`.  This means that `va_arg` cannot expect arguments of these types, otherwise you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This behavior with regard to variadic functions is documented in section 6.5.2.2p7 of the [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
> if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
> the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type. **The ellipsis notation in a function prototype
> declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last
> declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on
> trailing arguments.**

And the term **default argument promotions** is defined in 6.5.2.2p6:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does not include a prototype, **the integer promotions are performed
> on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to
> `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*.**

Comment: _The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter._ - according to this, `parmN` is the last declared parameter, so it shouldnt be affected by default argument promotions. [cstdarg.syn] clause from the question is about undefined behavior after `va_start`, not `va_args`. So thats exactly whats confusing - how wrong type of `parmN` can trigger UB after `va_start`, if it doesnt even undergo default argument promotions

Comment: @klezki The last **declared** parameter, which in this case is `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

- [C++ - Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)
- [C - Default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions)

In the C reference there is a good example for what is meant by the (confusing) statement:

```
int add_nums(int count, ...);
int sum = add_nums(2, 'c', true); // add_nums is called with three ints: (2, 99, 1)
```

And the C++ reference makes it very clear, that:

> When a variadic function is called, after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes additional conversions known as default argument promotions:
>
> ...
>
> Only arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, and class type arguments (after conversion) are allowed. However, ... (some other stuff)

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes, the default argument promotions are (part of) what C++ is talking about there, but if one consults the C language spec about this then one needs to be aware that the restrictions on the argument associated with `parmN` are all C++, not drawn from C at all.  In C, the default argument promotions apply to all the variable arguments, but not to the one associated with `parmN` (or other prototyped parameters).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Somehow i can not wrap my head around _"the default argument promotions apply to all the variable arguments, but not to the one associated with parmN"_. What are all variable arguments and those associated with parmN? Could you be more elaborate on this?

Comment: The "variable arguments" are those that do not correspond to declared parameters.  `parmN` is the last-declared [named] parameter.  Thus, in the OP's example, `parmN` is `count`, and the variable arguments for any given call to that function are the second and all subsequent ones.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you very much. It is clear to me now.