# default argument promotion of pointer

Tags: c, default-arguments

Which roles are used when i call a function with pointer argument unless declare the function before? I know that float are promoted to double and that are executed the integral promotion, but what happens at the pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. Default argument promotions don't apply to arguments of pointer type so they are left unchanged in type and value.

Comment: Simply because C99 "6.5.2.2 Function calls" 6 does not say anything about pointers when defining default argument promotions is that it (only integers and `float`?