# What is the difference between NULL and "0"?

Tags: null

What is the difference from NULL and "0"?

Example:

```
return NULL;
return 0;
```

Comment: In what language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conceptually, zero (0) is a number, and NULL is a value that represents "no value".  As such, 0 can be added, subtracted, etc., but NULL cannot.  The NULL value for a variable can indicate, for example, that a variable has not yet been assigned a value.

The semantics of NULL may vary by language or application.