# JVM 8 exit code -559038737 (0xDEADBEEF)

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

My application has started to non-deterministically fail after upgrading to Java 8. It doesn't throw an exception or print an error message. The only sign of its failure is the exit code -559038737. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: If you read the hex message, it says "dead beef". This is a common trick used by memory profilers to indicate invalid memory.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This an *exit code*, nothing to do with the contents of RAM. There must be a better explanation.

Comment: OP, your application may actually be calling `System.exit(0xDEADBEEF)` somewhere inside 3rd party code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I will kill the library author who used System.exit if I ever find him. I suppose I can try setting a breakpoint on that function. It does seem strange to use that magic number in Java source code rather than in C.

Comment: If my guess is right, you are using a Java library written by a C enthusiast. Sprinkling a bit of C magic over Java must have felt good :)

Comment: I haven't found any notions of `0xDEADBEEF` as an exit code in either JDK or HotSpot sources. This might be a library. Place a breakpoint on `java.lang.Runtime.exit` and on `java.lang.Runtime.halt` if possible. If it isn't possible to place a breakpoint on the production system, you may want to recomple `Runtime.java` class to print the stack trace on `exit` and `halt`.

Comment: @apangin What do you mean to recompile tgose classes? Is there a way I can include them in my source code and have them picked up instead of the official ones?

Comment: Yes, you can. Extract `java/lang/Runtime.java` from `src.zip` included in JDK, modify it as you wish, compile with javac, and finally include in the bootstrap classpath when running your application using `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alt/classes` command line option.

Comment: For the record, OXCAFEBABE seems to be more popular in JVM environments.

Comment: @apangin if I simply include it at `src/main/java/java/lang/Runtime.java` in my Maven project and build the jar, what JVM flag should I use?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/project.jar`

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: @Totoro The first 4 bytes of every valid Java .class file is 0xCAFEBABE.

Comment: Use SecurityManager and handle system exit - the rest leave untouched, it's few lines of code and can be used in production environment.

Comment: Something similar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907614/0xdeadbeef-vs-null

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky debug you application and post the snippet where `dead beef` occurs.

Comment: Yep, "DEADBEEF" is commonly used to initialize heap, etc, to detect invalid references (due to "dangling pointers", etc).  I would not expect a skilled programmer to intentionally use that value as a `exit` return code, so either the exit is due to an unskilled programmer or there has indeed been some sort of "wild" reference.

Comment: @Totoro - It would be a rather inexperienced programmer who initialize storage to "CAFEBABE", as that would lead to confusion as to whether the value had somehow been copied from a .class file header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That exit code probably comes from [Apache Commons Exec](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/exec/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/exec/Executor.java):

```
public interface Executor {

/** Invalid exit code. */
int INVALID_EXITVALUE = 0xdeadbeef;
...
```

There are some [changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) in Java 8 that might have introduced a bug.

But without knowing your classpath and code, this is just an educated guess.

Maybe you are using the asynchronous way to use Commons Exec:

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();

Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);

int exitValue = resultHandler.waitFor();

return exitValue;
```

So the exception is only captured in the resultHandler, but not print on stderr automatically?

Comment: I use Commons Exec to launch a JVM process. Do you think a JVM crash would cause Exec to return this exit code but not capture the error output that the JVM prints out? I have seen a similar issue in Java 8 where the stderr output is not recorded when the called java app uses System.Exit(). Output of a stack trace of an unhandled exception, though, seems to get recorded.

Comment: I edited the answer to address that question, maybe you are using the non-blocking way to use that library, which doesn't print the stacktrace automatically.

Comment: Not seeing (some) `stderr` output (or `stdout` for that matter) wouldn't be at all surprising on `System.exit()` since the output buffers won't get flushed, or might not on some JVMs.