# Why C++ compiler allows assigning 0 to pointers and no other number

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I was posting an answer to a question - and commenting it occured to me, thanks to another poster by the name **metal** that

C++ compiler allowed this:

`int *p = 0;` but not this `int *p = 1`. Is `0` considered a special number?

Edit: @DavidHefferman said `Is 0 special? In the context of a pointer, yes it is.` - why?

Comment: Is 0 special? In the context of a pointer, yes it is.

Comment: 0 is another representation of the null pointer constant.[See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Comment: It does allow `int* p = (int*)1;`. This will assign `1` to `int* p`.

`0` doesn't need a type, while all other values do. That is what makes it special.

Comment: @StarPilot That's not the whole story. `int *p = 0;` is defined and useful and always works, whereas `int *p = (int *)1;` is at best implementation-defined (I'm not sure, it might also be UB), almost always useless, and almost always completely wrong.

Comment: Nulls, nils, null pointers, void, void*, etc, will all end up defined as `0`. `0` effectively has many types.

Comment: In the end, the only real answer is: because the standard says so.  Historically, the inventors of C forgot to provide null pointers.  And the first implementations allowed implicit conversions of ints to pointers, so people got into the habit of using `0` for a null pointer constant.  C++ formalized this, but restricted it to integral constants evaluating to 0, and the standards committee of C took the C++ formalization (but added an additional legal possibility).

Comment: @StarPilot No.  `0` has type `int`.  Always.  But C++, like C, has a lot of implicit conversions.  This one is special, in that it only works for "integral expressions evaluating to 0".  (Note that `NULL` can be defined as `(1 - 1)`, although I've never seen it.  And for a long time, g++ defined it as `__builtin__nullptr`, or something like that---a compiler specific integral expression, which it could recognize, and generate a warning if it wasn't immediately converted to a pointer type.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 4.10 of the standard, Pointer conversions [conv.ptr] says:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero
>   or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result
>   is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or
>   pointer to function type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion. Two null pointer values of the
>   same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is
>   a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).
>   A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.

So, yes, `0` is a special value in the context of pointers.

Comment: ^ Accepted answer in 6 minutes

Comment: Note, however, that *constant* expression is important -- for example, something like `int i=0; int *p=i;` will *not* work, because `i` is not a constant expression (even though it's pretty obvious from reading it that it'll always contain the value 0).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Of course, you can force it with a `reinterpret_cast`.  But even then, the results of the conversion may be different than those resulting from the conversion of a null pointer constant.

Comment: In C++20 standard, the section is 7.3.12.

Answer (score 1):

0 is NULL, while 1 is an invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

"A null-pointer constant is an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero (such as 0 or 0L)."

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/

Comment: Ie. the number `0` is a null-pointer constant and thus can be assigned to a pointer without an explicit type-cast.