# Can the null character be used to represent the zero character?

Tags: c

The `C99` standard requires that "A byte with all bits set to 0, called the `null character`, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string." (5.2.1.2) It then goes on to list 99 other characters that must be in the execution set. Can a character set be used in which the null character is one of these 99 characters? In particular, is it allowed that `'0' == '\0'` ?

**Edit:** Everyone is pointing out that in ASCII, `'0'` is `0x30`. This is true, but the standard doesn't mandate the used of ASCII.

Comment: '0' has an ascii value of 48

Comment: why these downvotes? that is a legitimate question.

Comment: Note: _if_ `'0' == '\0'`, then `'1' == '\1', '2' == '\2'` up to `'9'` would need to be true also as "decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous".  Yet `'0' == '\0'`certainly has other issues.  Interesting out-of-the-box question - maybe too far out.

Answer (score 3):

No matter if you use ASCII, EBCDIC or something "self-crafted", `'0'` must be distinct from `'\0'`, for the reason you mention yourself:

> A byte with all bits set to 0, called the `null character`, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string. (5.2.1.2)

If the null character terminates a character string, it cannot be contained in that string. It is the only character which cannot be contained in a string; all other haracters can be used and thus must be distinct from 0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the standard states that each of the characters that it lists (including the null character) has a distinct value, other than that the digits do. But a "character set" containing a value `0` that allegedly represents 91 of the 100 required characters is clearly not really a character set containing the required 100 characters. So this is either:

- part of the English-language definition of "a character set",
- obvious from context,
- a very minor flaw in the text of the standard, that it should spell it out to prevent wilful misinterpretation by a faithless implementer.

Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the `'0'='\0'` you will not be able to differ end of string and `'0'` value.

Thus it will be a bit hard to use something like "0_any_string", as it already starts from `'0'`.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that the character set be ASCII. EBCDIC has been used, but any character set that fulfills the requirements of section 5.2.1 is allowed. I am asking if a hypothetical set with `'0'` having a value of `0` is compliant with the standard.

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to require that strings are able to contain all characters without terminating. So long as a you meet the requirement: "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character," you have a string, regardless of how well you can use it in practice.

Comment: Your first answer wasn't an answer to the question at all.

Comment: @JensGustedt Edited. Now it is a bit closer?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. Character set must be described by an injective function, i.e. a function that maps each character to exactly one distinct binary value. Mapping 2 characters to the same value will make the character set non-deterministic, i.e. the computer won't be able to interpret the data to a matching character since more than one fits.

The C99 standard poses another restriction by forcing the mapping of `null` character to a specific binary value. Given the above paragraph this means that no other character can have a value identical to `null`.

Comment: Certainly we would want the map to be injective, and it would be a flaw in the C standard if it failed to require this. But that does not mean the standard does contain such a requirement. Can you cite a part or parts of the C standard that require this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's not related to C standard but rather to a definition of character set (any). C standard is a user of character set in this aspect. Note the quote in the question "*A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set*" - this means that C language isn't supposed to support any character set that fails to comply. But being injective is a broader requirement and it goes beyond C scope.

Answer (score -1):

> The integer constant literal 0 has different meanings depending upon
>   the context in which it's used. In all cases, it is still an integer
>   constant with the value 0, it is just described in different ways.
>
> If a pointer is being compared to the constant literal 0, then this is
>   a check to see if the pointer is a null pointer. This 0 is then
>   referred to as a null pointer constant. The C standard defines that 0
>   cast to the type void * is both a null pointer and a null pointer
>   constant.

[What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)