# Is the NULL pointer implicitly converted to type (int*) when we use "if(ptr==NULL)" for an integer pointer ptr?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers, null-pointer

I know that a NULL pointer is `(void*)0`.But what happens when we use statements like the following:

```
  if(ptr==NULL)
```

where `ptr` can be a `char`,`float` or `int` pointer?Is **NULL** guaranteed to be implicitly converted to the type on the left just as, for example, in C, the type returned by `malloc()` is `void*` but is implicitly converted to the type of the lvalue?

Comment: strpbrk means "string pointer break"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) might answer your questions. Check the selected answer

Comment: Finally, NULL is _not_ necessarily "(void*)0". On some platforms (Darwin!) it's just plain "0". Watch out for it. In particular, never do "printf("%p",NULL)" or "system("thingy",NULL)" because it WILL NOT WORK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is NULL guaranteed to be implicitly converted to the type on the left? [...]

Yes.

According to section 6.3.2.3.4 of the [ISO/IEC 9899:2011 C programming language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null
>   pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.**

and to section 6.3.2.3.1

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type. **A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to
>   void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original
>   pointer.**

Answer (score 2):

> I know that a NULL pointer is `(void*)0`

Not necessarily. The macro NULL could be defined as `0`, `(void*)0` or something else. The only requirement is that it is compatible with a null pointer for the specific implementation. In theory, a compiler could define NULL as 1, but in practice nobody does that.

> Is NULL guaranteed to be implicitly converted to the type on the left

Yes, any expression where a null pointer is used together with another kind of pointer yields a null pointer. This has nothing to do with some implementations defining NULL as (void*). The C standard simply guarantees null pointer conversions, no matter the NULL macro.

> in C, the type returned by malloc() is void* but is implicitly converted to the type of the lvalue?

Yes, in C a `void*` will always be implicitly converted to/from a pointer of another type  (in C++, you would however need an explicit cast).

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens because of the `(void*)` part. A void pointer can point to *anything*. So comparing any pointer to `NULL` is quite okay.

Comment: the C standard establish that `void *` must be compatible with any other pointer type, and if your compiler follow the standard, you should never be worried about make assignments and comparisons using void pointers.

Comment: NULL isn't necessarily (void*)0, so to be picky and formal, this answer isn't correct.

Comment: @Lundin You are correct, but on the other hand it must be compatible with all pointer types, which basically means it _has_ to be a `void*`.