# Is there any difference in comparing a pointer with 0 or with NULL?

Tags: c, pointers

As far as i know, the NULL is actually not 0. So is there any difference in comparing a pointer with 0 or with NULL?
Further what should be the correct usage. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you would want to use `0` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: No, either is fine. Best (in my opinion) is not to use either butjust use ! Or use the pointer itself as a controlling expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Comment: @Gabe I came across a piece of code which had compared a pointer to 0. Hence the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct usage is to use `NULL` : It's more readable (`p == NULL` -> you know that `p` is a pointer)

Comment: "Correct" is a bit strong here.  It is more a matter of style.  Even if NULL ifs not zero, it is guaranteed to evaluate as equivalent.

Comment: I see wrong descriptions here. It may happen that the NULL pointer's binary representation doesn't consist of all 0 bits, but even then, `NULL == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

In C,the macro NULL is defined as an implementation-defined null pointer constant, which in C99 can be portably expressed as the integer value 0 converted implicitly or explicitly to the type `void*`.
In C++ NULL is the integer literal for zero (`0` or `0L`) has been traditionally preferred to represent a null pointer constant.

Compiler would implicitly convert `0` to `NULL` in case of comparison with a pointer.

It is always safe to compare `0` with `NULL`.

Comment: "Most compilers would implicitly convert 0 to NULL in case of comparison with a pointer."  Actually, this is required by the standard, so it should be "all compilers".

Comment: @DietrichEpp and Inafzier Thanks. I updated the statement.

Answer (score -1):

NULL is  not necessarily 0 and should only be used for pointers. 
NULL is a macro usually defined as (void*)0 but not always.

It's a pointer to no location in memory.

There's a very good new book called Understanding And Using C Pointers. Please read that one.

Don't use it for anything but pointers.

Comment: `NULL == 0`, always, but not its binary representation.

Comment: how is that different than what i wrote? NULL compares equal to zero but it is not necessarily actually 0.

Comment: You don't say in your answer that NULL compares as equal to zero.  That's what is different.

Comment: Well it does not invalidate my answer in the least. I state fact that it is not always zero.

Comment: @uchuugaka "...that it is not always *represented by* zero." That makes a difference.

Comment: Whatever. Now you're totally stepping into semantic nonsense. NULL is a macro that represents something not the other way around.