# OpenCV: Initialize the images

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am implementing some methods and i'm using OpenCv functions.

I work with many frames of a video and i need to implement the best code to avoid some problems with the memory. I have some doubts:

**Doubt 1**: How would it be better?

- **Option 1**:

  IplImage* image1 = NULL;

  ...

  IplImage* picture_sintetica(.. ){

  ```
  ...

  if (image1 == NULL){

      image1 = cvCreateImage( cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
  }

  ...
  ```

  }
- **Option 2**:

  IplImage* image1 = NULL;

  ...

  IplImage* picture_sintetica(...){

  ```
  ...

  image1 = cvCreateImage( cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

  ...
  cvReleaseImage(&image1);
  ```

  }

I think that in option 2, the image1 is created many times(each time the method named picture_sintetica is called) and with the option 1 it will be created only once, but I'm not sure...and in other examples i've seen using the option 2.

**Doubt 2:** Is it equivalent declare the image equal to zero (IplImage* image1 = 0;), to NULL (IplImage* image1 = NULL;) o to put anything (IplImage* image1;)?

**Doubt 3:** When is it recommendable to use the function named cvCloneImage and when is it better to use cvCopy?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from **Doubt3**, according with [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html), you should use cvCloneImage when you need a full copy of an image (including header, data and ROI).

**Doubt1:** looking at your code, there'are no reason to think image1 should created many times, unless your code is in a cicle.

**Doubt2:** i suggest to take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Comment: Thanks! The method named picture_sintetica is called every time that a frame of a video is decoded. The frame will be a param of the function and into this method it will call to OpenCV functions and it will create different images. Therefore,  i think that every time a frame is decoded, the image1 will be created in the option 2 and with the option 1 when the second frame is decoded and picture_sintetica is called, image1 isn't NULL and overwrite the last values in image1.