# Changing strings to upper within a double pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, toupper

I need to convert arguments given at command line such as: $ myprogram hello world

and the words need to be printed in CAPS. I am able to to do everything except access the double pointer array to make the changes with toupper()

```
static char **duplicateArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **copy = malloc(argc * sizeof (*argv));
    if(copy == NULL){
        perror("malloc returned NULL");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
         copy[i] = argv[i];   
    }
    char **temp;
    temp = &copy[1];
    *temp = toupper(copy[1]); 

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Looks like you are using vim, the shortcut for indenting the code is `GG=g`

Comment: `char **temp;
    temp = &copy[1];
    *temp = toupper(copy[1]); ` - what do you currently think this does?

Comment: Also, note that while you're copying `argv` itself (which is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings), you're not copying the individual strings.

Comment: Do you need "convert argument given at command line" or "convert argumentS given at command line"? As I see your example with `hello word` and `argc` parameter of `duplicateArgs` I suppose you want to process all the arguments, but accepted answer made me doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*temp = toupper(copy[1]);
```

`toupper` converts a single character, if you want to convert an entire string:

```
char *temp = copy[1]; /* You don't need a double pointer */
size_t len = strlen(temp);

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    temp[i] = toupper(temp[i]); 
}
```

Comment: @Slider on just in one line: `while(*temp++ = toupper(*tem));`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, wow, it's nice to see you again Mr ASCII-Art :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) of `toupper()` the function prototype is

> int toupper(int c);

In your code, the argument `copy[1]` is not an `int` value.

Instead what you want is to check each and every element, if they are in lower case, convert them to upper case. A pseudo-code will look like

```
for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
         copy[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+ 1);  //allocate memory 

for (j = 1; j < argc; j++)
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[j]); i++)
  {
    if (islower(argv[j][i]))   //check if it is lower case
         copy[j-1][i] = toupper(argv[j][i]);
    else
         copy[j-1][i] = argv[j][i];          //do not convert
  }
```

Comment: correct, because I am trying to convert to upper the characters inside the string which pointer copy[1] points to. How can I do it then?

Comment: @Slider Please Check the updated answer. It checks for lowercase and then converts.

Comment: @dear downvoter, please let me know the reason behind the downvote. Kindly consider leaving a comment so that the post can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the argument that is passed into your function `char **argv` is passed directly from main, so it represents a pointer to the beginning of an array of pointers to each of the command line arguments.

`argc` represents the number of command line arguments.

Inside your function, you create a new buffer, and then copy the contents of argv into it. So you are creating a copy of the array of pointers to the command line arguments, NOT the command line argument strings themselves.

I am guessing you intended to copy the strings, rather than the pointers to the strings (what would be the point of that?). I suggest you look into the functions strdup and/or strncpy to copy the actual strings.

This also explains with the 'toupper' does not work as you expect - instead of passing a single character to it, you are passing a pointer to a null terminated string of characters.

Comment: yes, I call the function with main, passing the argc and argv, in my function they come in as int argc and char **argv  You are suggesting i copy the string, then apply toupper()??

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an error using the `toupper()` function because you are trying to pass in a string instead of an individual letter. Here is an excerpt from the man page describing the function:

```
DESCRIPTION
     The toupper() function converts a lower-case letter to the corresponding
     upper-case letter.  The argument must be representable as an unsigned
     char or the value of EOF.
```

You have a pointer to a pointer which you could visulize as something like this. In C a string is just an array of `char`s so you need to dereference twice to get the data in the second level of arrays (the individual letter). Every time you add an `*` you can think of it as removing one layer of pointers. And you can think of the `*` operator as the inverse of the `&` operator.

This line is your problem line

```
temp = &copy[1];
```

try this instead

```
//This is a pointer to an individual string
char *temp = copy[1];
//Keep going while there are letters in the string
while(*temp != NULL) {
    //convert the letter
    toupper(*temp);
    //Advance the pointer a letter
    temp++;
}
```

Comment: `while (*temp  != null)` should be `while  (*temp != '\0')`

Comment: @AlterMann I maybe should have used `\0` for clarity but it should work just the same the way I wrote it. `NULL` is typedefed to be 0 and `\0` is the octal number 0, both hold the same value are are thus equivalent. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

static char **duplicateArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **copy = NULL;
    // allocate memry for pointers to new lines
    copy = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc);
    int line, chr;
    for(line = 0; line < argc; line++)
    {
        // allocate memory for new line
        copy[line] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(argv[line]) + 1));
        // copy with changes
        for(chr = 0; chr <= strlen(argv[line]); chr++)
        {
            copy[line][chr] = toupper(argv[line][chr]);
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char ** strs;
    int i;
    strs = duplicateArgs(argc, argv);
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also you can make a decision about using argv[0] (name of executable file) and change a code if you need. Also checking of `malloc` result can be added, and other improvements... if you need :-)