# Understanding NULL pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, null

I have  found in some code `NULL` pointer is defined as follows -

```
#define NULL ((char *)0)
```

I found these code compiles fine. But I did not understand how this works. Can anyone please explain how 0 is casted to a `char` pointer?

And is it valid to use it as a FILE pointer making null -

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
```

Comment: It works...poorly (in fact, I don't think it's allowed). You want `((void *)0)` instead. As to how it works: the standard defines a conversion from an integer constant with the value 0 to a pointer, and specifies that the result will always be a null pointer.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, yes you are right. While compiling the code I found the code compiles without any error but with the following warning - `warning: "NULL" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/stddef.h:402:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition`  But I did not understand how this works.

Comment: I think this question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Comment: Once upon a long time ago, that was the normal way to write NULL; we are talking about in the 1980s here, before there was a standard and before `void *` was uniformly supported.  When the C standard was published (1989. 1990), it became less appropriate; it should be a `((void *)0)` instead.  Maybe your code is old enough that it is using the pre-standard definition.

Comment: `((char *)0)` is not a valid null pointer constant (in C since the 1989 ANSI standard) and therefore not a valid definition for `NULL`. Given that definition, `FILE *fp = NULL;` is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic (and perhaps rejecting the program).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Do you have a citation for that? *Any* type can have an appropriately typed nullpointer, and the fact that you may round-trip pointers of one type through pointers of another suggests that you could well use `(char*)0` as a general nullpointer, with the caveat that you have to do explicit casts.

Comment: @EOF: Certainly evaluating the expression `((char *)0)` yields a null pointer at runtime. But it is not a *null pointer constant*, which is defined as a constant integer expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to `void*`. It's a plausible definition of `NULL` for a pre-ANSI implementation, which may or may not have required a cast when assigning to another pointer type.

Comment: Any integer can easily be casted to any kind of pointer since these no real difference between a pointer and an integer: just consider the pointer as a memory address, which IS an integer.

Comment: @JoëlHecht And whiat do you do about the implementations which don't use all-0s for the internal null pointer representation? In fact, there can be huge differences between pointers and integers. Just think about the old MS-DOS age/Real Mode pointer model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C library Macro NULL is the value of a null pointer constant.It may be defined as **((void*)0), 0 or 0L** depending on the **compiler vendor.**
Depending on compiler,declaration of NULL can be

```
#define NULL ((char *)0)
```

or

```
#define NULL 0L
```

or

```
#define NULL 0
```

> And is it valid to use it as a FILE pointer making null--> 
>   Yes.