# simulating a Null Pointer undefined behaviour in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to simulate the null pointer undefined behaviour.
What changes should be made in the below code to introduce null pointer undefined behaviour.

```
void foo( int * d )
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 7 ;
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
    foo(b) ;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding NULL pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379663/understanding-null-pointer-in-c)

Comment: it explained the null pointer exception,
but i wanted to know how to introduce the null pointer exception here.
can you please remove the duplicate flag

Comment: There are no exceptions in C, so there cannot be any `NULL` pointer exception in C.

Comment: Actually the question is wrong and meaningless, because C don't have exceptions. You need to understand what **undefined behavior** means.

Comment: HI Basile, thanks for pointing out that its undefined behavior and not exceptions. I was requesting for assistance in simulating the undefined behavior in C for null pointer dereferencing. The answer mr.Eric Tsui gave was what i was requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, we can simulate  Null Pointer UB like this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo( int * d )
{
    printf("hello, it is %d\n", *d);//dereference d (produces "Segmentation fault" if d is NULL)
}

int main(void)
{
    int a  = 7 ;
    int *b = NULL; // simulate failed to malloc(sizeof(int))

    foo(&a); // output is "hello, it is 7"
    foo(b); // will trigger something like "Segmentation fault"
}
```

As pointed by @Basile Starynkevitch, *there are no exceptions in C*, so here it would be more accurate to say "NULL pointer UB(Undefined Behaviour)" compared to "NULL pointer exception".

Comment: Wrong. There is no exception here, just some **undefined behavior**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Agree. Because the question is marked as `c` tag, and 'c' is without exception. So I assumed what the question owner mean for "null pointer exception" is some "abnormal behaviour" caused by NULL pointer, i.e. UB. Anyway, you are right. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hence my answer is (IMHO) the correct one, not yours! :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  I have updated my answer to change 'exception' to 'UB' to make it more accurate.  And. I'd like +1 to your answer for your help to refine the answer:)

Answer (score 3):

**Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer** (or some address outside your current [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), often in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) in C **is** *not* an [exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), but **some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** (often a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)). You [really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) should avoid UB.

By definition of undefined behavior, we cannot explain it without going down into very specific implementation details (compiler, runtime, optimization, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), machine code, phase of the moon, ...).

The `malloc` library function can (and does) fail. You should always test it, at least as:

```
 int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
 if (!b) { perror("malloc of int"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

To trigger failure of `malloc` (but very often the first few calls to `malloc` would still succeed) you might lower the available address space to your program. On Linux, use `ulimit` in the parent shell, or call [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).

BTW, you could even link with your own `malloc` which is always failing:

```
  // a silly, standard conforming, malloc which always fail:
  void* malloc(size_t sz) {
    if (sz == 0) return NULL;
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
  }
```

**The *C* programming language does not have exceptions**. C++ (and Ocaml, Java, ....) does (with `catch` & `throw` statements). Raising an exception is a non-local change of control flow. In standard C you might use `longjmp` for that purpose. In C++ dereferencing a `nullptr` is UB (and does not raise any null-pointer exception which does not exist in C++).

Comment: Thanks mr. Basile, updated the question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to dereference a null pointer:

```
 int *b = 0;
 *b = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Buddy, can you please what you exactly the code is doing?

Comment: No with a standard C perspective. It is an undefined behavior.