# Printing an array of characters with "while"

Tags: c, string

So here is the working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char myText[] = "hello world\n";
    int counter = 0;
    while(myText[counter]) {
        printf("%c", myText[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and in action:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ gcc koray.c
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ ./a.out 
hello world
```

My question is, why is this code even working? When (or how) does

```
while(myText[counter])
```

evaluate to false?

These 2 work as well:

```
while(myText[counter] != '\0')
while(myText[counter] != 0)
```

This one prints garbage in the console:

```
while(myText[counter] !=  EOF)
```

and this does not even compile:

```
while(myText[counter] != NULL)
```

I can see why the `'\0'` works, as C puts this character at the end of my array in compile time. But why does not `NULL` work? How is `0 == '\0'`?

Comment: `myText[counter]` is equivalent to `myText[counter] != '\0'`. checking nul character. `\0` is equivalent to `0` therefore `myText[counter] != 0` is valid too.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why do you even bother to insult people?

Comment: @KorayTugay C is not well suited to learn by trial and error, because you never know if you are seeing standard behaviour or undefined behaviour. You really will save yourself a lot of time by learning from a good book

Comment: @ Koray That comment by @MattMcNabb has nothing personal, don't be offended, :-)

Comment: @MattMcNabb You did not answer my question. Why do you bother insulting people?

Comment: You can increase the quality of the post and answers by posting different questions as separate posts.

Comment: `EOF` doesn't work because `'\0'==0` but `EOF==-1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS for your last question,

> *But why does not NULL work?*

Usually, `NULL` is a pointer type. Here, `myText[counter]` is a value of type `char`. As per the conditions for using the `==` operator, from `C11` standard, chapter 6.5.9,

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> 1. both operands have arithmetic type;
>
>    both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>
>    one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>
>    one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

So, it tells, you can ***only*** compare a pointer type with a *null pointer constant* <sup>##</sup> (`NULL`).

After that,

> *When (or how) does `while(myText[counter])` evaluate to false?*

Easy, when `myText[counter]` has got a value of `0`.

To elaborate, after the *initialization*, `myText` holds the character values used to initialize it, with a "null" at last. The "null" is the way C identifies the *string* endpoint. Now, the null, is represented by a values of `0`. So, we can say. when the *end-of-string* is reached, the `while()` is *FALSE*.

*Additional explanation:*

- `while(myText[counter] != '\0')` works, because `'\0'` is the representation of the "null" used as the string terminator.
- `while(myText[counter] != 0)` works, because `0` is the decimal value of `'\0'`.

Above both statements are *equivalent* of `while(myText[counter])`.

- `while(myText[counter] !=  EOF)` does not work because a null is not an `EOF`.

---

Reference: (#)

Reference: `C11` standard, chapter 6.3.2.3, *Pointers*, Paragraph 3

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.

and, from chapter, 7.19,

> NULL
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant

---

Note: In the end, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/2173917) and realted answers will clear the confusion, should you have any.

Answer (score 2):

> When (or how) does this work?

```
while(myText[counter])
```

Any built-in with value zero will evaluate to false in a boolean context. So this  `while(myText[counter])` is false when `myText[counter]` is `'\0'`, which has the value `0`.

> How is 0 == '\0'?

It is defined that way in the language. `'\0'` is an `int` literal with value zero. `0` is also an `int` literal with value zero, so both compare equal, and they both evaluate to false in a boolean context

Comment: So \0 equals 0 ? Then how is 0 different than \0 ?

Comment: @KorayTugay Yes, but `'\0'` is  char literal with value zero. `0` is an `int` literal with value zero. They both compare equal after type conversions, and they both evaluate to false in a boolean context.

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually `'\0'` is not a `char`, but an `int` too (in C).

Comment: @KorayTugay , It would be easier if you think that `0=='\0'`. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

In C, any non-zero value evaluates to true. C strings are null-terminated. That is, there is a special zero-value character after the last character in the string.

And so when the null terminator is reached, the zero value evaluates to false, and the loop terminates.

> I can see why the '\0' works, as C puts this character at the end of my array in compile time. But why does not NULL work? How is 0 == '\0'?

0 has the same value as '\0' because '\0' is a character with the value zero. (Not to be confused with '0', which is the zero digit and has a value of 48.)

Regarding `NULL`, that actually can work since it also evaluates to zero. However, `NULL` is a pointer type so you may have to type cast to avoid errors. (Hard to say for certain since you didn't post the error that you got.)

Comment: complie time error is: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *')

Comment: Yes, as I indicated you may need a type cast to convert `NULL` to an integer. But that's kind of silly since `NULL` is basically zero cast to a pointer. Makes more sense to compare against 0.

Answer (score 1):

> How is 0 == '\0'?

All characters have an 8-bit numeric value, for example, 'a' is 97 (decimal). The backslash in the character literal '\0' introduces an "escape" to directly specify the character through its numeric value. In this case, the numeric value 0.

Comment: Ahh, I did not know that. Thanks. So \1 equals 00000001 ?

Comment: Yes, \nnn gives a character with nnn as its octal numeric value. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape

Answer (score 1):

1. The termination of a string is `\0`
2. `NULL` is used to initialise a pointer to a determined value

`while(myText[counter])` evaluates to false as soon as `counter` points to the zero byte.

In the end there is nothing different than a zero byte at the end of the string. Actually `NULL` would mean the same but it is used for notation purposes only in the context of pointers.

If something is not 100% clear from a coding perspective, you might want to look inside your debugger watch window, what are the bits and bytes actually during program execution.

Comment: "*... and a pointer not yet being initialised NULL*" this somehow is incomplete, isn't it? I simply do not get what you want to express.

Comment: Yes, it was not complete. I rewrote the first paragraph.

Comment: "*A pointer which is not yet initialised is NULL*" this not correct. An unitialised variable has an *undetermined* value. To have a pointer carry `NULL` it explicitly needs be assigned: `char * p = NULL;`. And since C99 you also could to `char * p = 0;`

Comment: What I want to say is: NULL is used to initialise a pointer to a determined value :)