# what is difference between 9-'0' and '9'-'0' in C?

Tags: c

In my following code:

```
main(){
    int c;
    char c1='0';
    int x=9-c1;
    int y='9'-c1;
}
```

Now in this program I'm getting value of x as some arbitrary value, but the value of y is 0, which is the value that I expect. Why this difference?

Comment: One is using the ASCII value and the other the `int` value.

Comment: Do you really expect `y` to be zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good explanation. Just compile it and run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c;
    char c1='0';
    int x=9-c1;
    int y='9'-c1;
    printf("--Code and Explanation--\n");
    printf("int c;\n");
    printf("char c1='0';\n");
    printf("int x=9-c1;\n");
    printf("int y='9'-c1;\n");
    printf("c1 as char '0' has decimal value: %d\n", c1);
    printf("decimal 9 - decimal %d or c1 = %d or x\n", c1, x);
    printf("char '9' has decimal value %d - decimal %d or c1 = %d\n", '9', c1, y);
    printf("Your Welcome :)\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt in this question , how its is able to generate correct output, in array we are writing a[c-'0'], c is an int ? therfore it should be -ve #include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];
nwhite = nother = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
ndigit[i] = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
++ndigit[c-'0'];
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
++nwhite;
else
++nother;
printf("digits =");
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
nwhite, nother);
}

Comment: What is probably a better question is why are you asking about arrays when the original question doesn't contain them.

Comment: @AmanBisht put those codes into `backticks` to make it readable. If it isn't relevant to the question, ask it in another different question

Answer (score 3):

1st `char` are integers.
2nd `char`s *might* have a printable representation or output controlling function (like for ASCII: `TAB`, `CR`, `LF`, `FF`, `BELL` ...) depending on the character set in use.

For ASCII

```
char c = 'A';
```

is the same as

```
char c = 65;
```

is the same as

```
char c = 0x41;
```

Another character set widely in use for example is [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). It uses a different mapping of a character's integer value to its printable/controling representation.

Internally always the *same* integer value is used/stored.

The printable, often but not always [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) representation of, for example `65` or `0x41`, which is `A`, is only used when

1. either printing out using the `printf()`-family along with the ***conversion*** specifiers `%s` or `%c` or `puts()`
2. or scanning in using the `scanf()`-family along with the ***conversion*** specifiers `%s` or `%c` or `fgets()`
3. or when coding literals like `'A'` or `"ABC"`.

On all other operation only the `char`'s integer value is used.

Answer (score 2):

When you do calculations with `char`s, you have to keep in mind that to **you** it looks like a '0' or '9', but the compiler interprets is as its [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) value, which is 48 for '0' and 57 for '9'.

So when you do:

```
int x=9-c1;
```

the result is 9 - 48 = -39. And for

```
int y='9'-c1;
```

the result is 57 - 48 = 9.

Comment: Nitpicking: "*`c1` is cast to its ASCII value*" not quiet right, as a) there is no cast, b) `char`s **are** integers, so even if there were a cast it woudn't be necessary. The character literal `'9'` is stored as integer, also no cast here, nor necessary.

Comment: Thanks - I meant 'cast' as seen from the programmer's point of view. 'Interpreted' is probably better.

Comment: C does not mandate a specific encoding, nor does it even mention the word "ASCII" except in some excursive footnotes.

Comment: I have a doubt in follw. prog. , how its is able to generate correct output, in array we are writing a[c-'0'], c is an int ? therfore it should be -ve #include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];
nwhite = nother = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
ndigit[i] = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
++ndigit[c-'0'];
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
++nwhite;
else
++nother;
printf("digits =");
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
nwhite, nother);
}

Comment: @AmanBisht hard to say without formatting - and you should ask that in a new question.

Comment: @KerrekSB you're right, but I think that introducing the notion of character sets will confuse the OP even more.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Except for decimal digits, where 5.2.1 of the C Standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) states:  "the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous".  I only note this because it's applicable to the question, especially after the comments above.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's not "ASCII". That's just saying that numeral characters have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (5.2.1 Character sets)

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, **the value of 
>      each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>      one greater than the value of the previous**.

Thus expression `'9' - '0'` has the same value like `9 - 0` and is equal to 9 whether you are using for example the ASCII table of characters or the EBCDIC.

Expression `9 - '0'` is implementation defined and depends on the coding table you are using. But in any case the value of the internal representation of character `'0'` is greater then `9`. (`9` is the value of the tab character representation `'\t'`)

For example in the ASCII the value of the code of character `'0'` is equal to `48`.
In the EBCDIC the value of `'0'` is equal to `240`.

So you will get that `9 - '0'` is some negative number.

For example it is equal to `-39` if the character representations are based on the ASCII table or `-231` if the character representations are based on the EBCDIC table.

You can see this yourself running this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", 9 - '0' );
}
```

You could write the printf statement also in the following way;)

```
printf( "%d\n", '\t' - '0' );
```

because `9` as I mentioned is the value of the internal representation of the escape character `'\t'` (tab).