# The difference between 0 and '0' in array

Tags: c++, literals

I have a question about array initialization

What is the difference between

char a[6]={0};

and

char a[6]={'0','0','0','0','0','0'};

How does the compiler interpret the above two expression? Are they just the same or not??

Comment: It has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'0'` is the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character for the number 0. Its value is 48.

The constant `0` is a *zero byte* or *null byte*, also written `'\0'`.

These four are equivalent:

```
char a[6] = {0};
char a[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
char a[6] = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
char a[6] = "\0\0\0\0\0"; // sixth null byte added automatically by the compiler
```

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` is a character which is displayed (e.g. on a screen) so it looks like a zero.   In all standard character sets, it has a non-zero numeric value.   For example, in the ASCII character set it has numeric value `48`.

`0` is a literal which yields a numeric value of zero.  `'\0'` is a literal which gives a character with numeric value of zero.

Putting values into an array does not change this.

You can test this using something like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Character \'0\' does "
    if (0 != '0') std::cout << "not ";
    std::cout << "have numeric value zero\n";

    std::cout << "Character \'\\0\' does "
    if (0 != '\0') std::cout << "not ";
    std::cout << "have numeric value zero\n";
    return 0;
}
```

which will always print out

```
Character '0' does not have numeric value zero
Character '\0' does have numeric value zero
```

Some compilers may give a warning on the above code because `0` (unadorned) is of type `int`, `'0'` is of type `char`, and `'\0'` is also of type `char`.   (There may also be warnings because the comparisons involve values known at compile time).  The comparisons are allowed, but involve type conversions which can indicate programmer mistakes in some circumstances.