# Is initializing char array as 0 and '\0' the same?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

In C++, to initialize all ***1D-array*** elements as zeroes:

```
int array[5] = {0};  //Set all elements to zeroes.
```

To initialize every element of an int ***2D-array*** to zeroes, we can do this:

```
int matrix[5][5] = {0}; //Set all elements to zeroes.
```

---

So if I am not using functions like `memset` and just populating the ***2D-array*** of `char` with "empty values". I probably can do this:

```
char matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {'\0'}; //Set all elements to '\0'
```

**So my question is:** 
Can I safely assume it is the same as writing it as `char matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {0};` since the ASCII value of `'\0'` is `0` ?

I have tested the output, initializing it as `\0` and `0` seems to be the same. But will it always work the same way in different OS or different compilers?

---

*Some pages I have already visited:*

[What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

[The difference between 0 and '0' in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918600/the-difference-between-0-and-0-in-array)

*PS: I am not asking difference of 0 and '0'. I am asking about 0 and '\0'.*

Comment: Both of the questions you linked have answers that answer your question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Hmm, that is probably true. Maybe I should delete this question? So just a confirmation, init with `0` and `\0` is the same right?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am actually more concern whether I can use it interchangeably by initializing with `0` and `\0`. It should work the same regardless what OS or compiler I am using. Am I right?

Comment: @user3437460 Yes. IMO, '\0' provides more readability when dealing with `char` array but it could be used interchangeably.

Comment: @MukulGupta Thanks for your confirmation ;)

Comment: Yes, as stated in the dupes, `'\0' == 0`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `= {};` is better than all of the options listed so far, because it works for all types  (well, all default-constructable ones)

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't have a good answer posted for C++

Comment: ASCII has nothing to do with it; `'\0'` means character code zero

Comment: @M.M `The linked duplicate doesn't have a good answer posted for C++` Totally agree with you. Maybe you can vote to reopen this question. I will gladly accept your solution if you provide one.

Comment: someone posting a good answer on the other thread would probably be the better way to go