# null and NULL , Is there any difference?

Tags: c, pointers, character

Is there any difference between `null` and `NULL` ? 
I know null character (`'\0'`) other than that any co-relation between them ?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/694576

Comment: Yes.  If you use the wrong one, you get warnings and/or errors.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. When asking about something, it is in general a good idea to provide the necessary definitions and use markdown.

Comment: "null" does not exist in the C language.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is a macro that yields a null pointer constant (typically a plain, unadorned `0` or `0L` in C++, and `((void *)0)` in C). In modern C++, `nullptr` is usually the preferred way to get a null pointer constant though.

`NUL` is the ASCII designation for a zero-byte. The C standard calls this a "null character".

"null" is a normal word. In C++, its primary use is as part of the phrase "null pointer" (or "null pointer constant").

Comment: In C++, using `NULL` or `0` is deprecated. Use `nullptr` instead. Not sure about C++, but in C, `\0` is also a _null pointer constant_. It should not be used just by convention.

Comment: and `0LL`, `0ULL`, `0U`, `0UL` and `0x0000000` and `00`, `(1+2-3)` and `(7 / 3 - 2)` are all *null pointer constants* in C.

Comment: "null" is also used extensively in C as part of _null character_: `'\0'`.