# Split String using SQL's REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to split a string like this

```
RANDOM(NUL)THIS_SHOULD_BE_SPLIT(NUL)~THIS_IS_NEW(NUL)STRING(NUL)~THIS_IS_ANOTHER_STRING(NUL)
```

`(NUL)` means a character with ASCII value `0`. Don't know how to type it here.

I need to split this when `(NUL)~` occurs.

So the expected result after split is

1. `RANDOM(NUL)THIS_SHOULD_BE_SPLIT`
2. `THIS_IS_NEW(NUL)STRING`
3. `THIS_IS_ANOTHER_STRING(NUL)`

Using OracleDB not sure how it handles NULL characters and if it is possible to split it.

To split it using ~ I am using

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(stringval,'[^~]+', 1, LEVEL) AS error_code
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(stringval, '[^~]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Have no idea on how to incorporate NULL character here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly match the `ASCII 0 (NUL)` character in a regular expression as the [regular expression parser will treat an `ASCII 0 (NULL)` character as a string terminator and end the regular expression pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461369/chr0-in-regexp-like) rather than using it as a character to match. So, if you want to use regular expressions, you will need to replace all occurrences of the `ASCII 0 (NUL)` character with a placeholder string and then match that when splitting and then restore the `ASCII 0 (NUL)` characters that were not split upon afterwards. But you will need to ensure that your placeholder is never going to occur elsewhere in your string.

Instead, you can use `CHR(0)` to match the `NUL` character. This method uses simple string functions (rather than slow regular expressions that cannot directly handle `ASCII 0 (NUL)` characters) and can handle multiple input rows:

```sql
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'RANDOM' || CHR(0)
         || 'THIS_SHOULD_BE_SPLIT' || CHR(0)
         || '~THIS_IS_NEW' || CHR(0)
         || 'STRING' || CHR(0)
         || '~THIS_IS_ANOTHER_STRING' || CHR(0)
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT '12345' || CHR(0)
         || '67890' || CHR(0)
         || '~23456'
  FROM   DUAL
),
split_positions ( value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value, 1, INSTR( value, CHR(0) || '~' )
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value, end_pos + 2, INSTR( value, CHR(0) || '~', end_pos + 2 )
  FROM   split_positions
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( value, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END AS value
FROM   split_positions;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                           |
> | :------------------------------ |
> | RANDOM(NUL)THIS_SHOULD_BE_SPLIT |
> | 12345(NUL)67890                 |
> | THIS_IS_NEW(NUL)STRING          |
> | 23456                           |
> | THIS_IS_ANOTHER_STRING(NUL)     |
> ```

*(Note: the `NUL` character has again been replaced by `(NUL)` string in the output as db<>fiddle did not like displaying that character.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=21c253ed2a0a72799c9f94c86305512c)*

Comment: Please explain the query. @MTO

Comment: @Akshith The first sub-query factoring clause (`WITH data .... `) has the input strings. The second sub-query factoring clause (`split_positions ....`) is a recursive query that starts finding the first `(NUL)~` and then iterates finding successive positions. The final `SELECT ...` statement just outputs the sub-strings between the positions that the previous recursive SQFC has found.

Comment: @Akshith Also added a section on why it won't directly work with regular expressions due to how the underlying parser expects `ASCII 0 (NUL)` characters to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be ok for you:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(replace(stringval, '(NUL)~', '~'),'[^~]+', 1, LEVEL) 
       AS error_code 
FROM test
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(stringval, '[^~]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=089273513e505632fa1fe8efb44ef0af)

Comment: No, as there might be other ~ which are not part of (NUL)~

Comment: By the way "(NUL)" is not a string. It is the character with ASCII value 0. I don't know how to represent it here or in SQL so I used (NUL) like a placeholder.

Comment: Ok but then you can just replace "(NUL)~" with something special like -xxx- and then use -xxx- as separator... I understand that the "(NULL)" is a placeholder...