# Converting string to char*

Tags: c, arrays, string, arraylist, malloc

When I try to convert a `char[]` to `char*` there are unneeded characters added to the `char*` variable

```
 int keySize = getKeySize(key2);
 char* key = (char*)malloc(sizeof(keySize));
 int i;
 char s[keySize-1];
 int i2;

 for(i2=0; i2<keySize; i2++)
 {
     s[i2] = getCharacter(key2, i2);
 }

 strncpy(key, s, keySize);
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what you want to do and what really happens. But the last iteration of the loops writes on not allocated memory(1 behind your array), so it is UB already.

Comment: sizeof(keySize) returns the size of int, which is usually 4 bytes. you sure it's what you want? afterwards you are copying (keySize) number of bytes to key

Comment: `char s[keySize-1];` is wrong, if the keysize was `1`, you try to allocate memory for `0` bytes. Get rid of the `-1`. Also, `sizeof(keysize)` will return your the size of the variable in memory, which is 4/8 bytes in your case, get rid of the `sizeof`. That will, however, not solve your problem. Extend your question and show us the code of `getCharacter()` function.

Comment: Does `keySize` include the string terminator? If it doesn't you end up with a `key` that isn't `NUL`-terminated which would explain the "unneeded characters".

Comment: What is `key2` and how had it been initialised?

Comment: Also what *exactly* is returned by `getKeySize()`

Comment: I want the code to be able to assign the same key to inputs which are the same.

Comment: getCharacter currently gets a char from an array list, so it has no problem and getkeySize, gets the value of an inputted string

Answer (score 1):

There is no string data type in C programming language. Strings in C are represented as array of characters.

**Note: C-Strings are actually character array terminated by '\0' character. That means, last character in any C-String in C will be used to store a '\0' character which marks the end of the string. To store `n` characters in C-String in C, you should define a character array of size `(n+1)`.**

> Why should we terminated it by '\0'?

The `'\0' termination` is what differentiates a `char array` from a `c-string` in `C programming language`. Most string-manipulating functions (like `strcpy`) relies on '\0' character to know when the string is finished (and its job is done!), and won't work with simple char-array (eg. they'll keep on working past the boundaries of the array, and continue until it finds a '\0' character somewhere in memory - often corrupting memory as it goes).

Therefore, storing a '\0' character (at the end) is necessary if you want to use functions of `#include <string.h>` like `strcpy()` as they rely on '\0' character to mark the end of the character array.

**'\0' is defined to be a null character - that is a character with all bits set to zero (and thus has a value 0). This has nothing to do with pointers. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0).**

In your program, you want two character arrays `key (dynamically allocated)` and `s` to hold a copy of another character array `key2` of size `keysize`. Then, both character arrays should be of atleast `keysize + 1` (+1 to hold a '\0' character) size.

Change:

```
char* key = (char*)malloc(sizeof(keySize));
```

To:

```
char* key = malloc(keySize+1); // Don't Type-Cast malloc
```

And

Change:

```
char s[keySize-1];
```

To

```
char s[keySize+1];
```

Comment: Correction: "Null" does not exist. It is either the CL word "null", or the ASCII `nul` (lower case to avoid confusing with `NULL`), or - as you further wrote `'\0'`, which I'd recommend to use in this context. It is **never ever** `NULL` which is a macro with a _null pointer constant_, very different semantics and typically a very different type, too (`void *`). Or is is simply `0`.

Comment: Read my comment carefully again. Syntax matters. And please only use code-markdown for code, not normal text.

Comment: I have edited my answer!

Comment: FYI: It is not my DV.

Answer (score 0):

1. While allocating, you should allocate one more than the size. Currently you are allocating 4 bytes only.

   ```
   char* key = (char*)malloc(keySize+1);
   //instead of
   char* key = (char*)malloc(sizeof(keySize));
   ```
2. `s` should have a size of `keySize+1`

   ```
   char s[keySize+1];
   // instead of
   char s[keySize-1];
   ```

Comment: Actually, he doesn't really need to add `+1` to the array size, if he doesn't want null terminated string, however, he does not provide enough information what he is about to do.

Comment: Still does the same thing the value of key is "can°<<<<<<<..." when I debug

Comment: @harleydave22 You also need to change the `strncpy` to `strncpy(key, s, keySize + 1);` to include the string terminator. Or add it explicitly if the source string isn't `NUL`-terminated

Comment: I want the code to be able to assign the same key to inputs which are the same.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
There are some errors about the dimension of s, I suggest you tu use [strncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strncpy.html)

```
       #include <string.h>
    int main(){
             //bla bla ... 
      int keySize = getKeySize(key2);
      char* key = malloc(keySize+1);;
      int i2;

      for(i2=0; i2<keySize; i2++){
        s[i2] = getCharacter(key2, i2);
      }
      char s[keySize+1];
      strncpy(s, key, sizeof s - 1); 
      s[keySize] = '\0';
      r

return 0;
}
```

Anyway more information about it please,I supposed you wanted this

Comment: Close! I want the code to be able to assign the same key to inputs which are the same. When I debug your code the address of key is different when the array in s is the same

Comment: It is the start of a hash function

Comment: The value in s is successfully copied but the address changes each time, I run the program, I would like the address of key to be the same when two strings are the same.

Comment: Why do you want to do with that address?