# NULL assignment to a string causing warning message

Tags: c

I understand that the definition of a string in C is that the string has to have NUL character at the end.  I am also aware that the following statements creates NUL character of a string:

```
 str[4] = 0;
 str[4] = '\0';
```

However, when you use this statement

```
 str[4] = NULL;
```

I am getting this message:

```
string1.c:15:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer 
without a cast [enabled by default]
```

My understanding of NULL is that it is a macro with the definition of ((void *)0).  Now why is this assignment causing this warning message?  What this warning message really mean? Can someone translate this message so that it is easier to understand?

Comment: NUL is a character, which, in C, is a type of integer. NULL is a pointer.  Does that help?

Comment: See  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Comment: @zwol - Is there a way to use NULL to a string without getting this warning message?

Comment: @Nguai al - Why would you want to assign NULL to a character? NULL is for pointers. If you want the `\0` char, Just use it directly instead of using the macro NULL.

Comment: @Nguaial Sure there is. But here, you are trying to assign `NULL` to `str[4]` which is a *character*. You could do: `const char *j = "hello"; j = NULL;`. Here `j` is a string that you then assign `NULL` to.

Comment: @Nguaial Yes, to assign NUL to an element of a string, write `str[n] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` and the NUL `\0` are very different things. NULL is an implementation-defined macro that is defined to be either `0`, `(char*)0`, or `(void*)0`, And if your implementation uses either `(void*)0` or `(char*)0` then to assign it to a `char` it would be implicitly converted to an integer(`char`s are just 1-byte-integers). The NUL `\0` character on the other hand, Is a byte-size 0.

Comment: However `NULL` is defined for a specific implementation, it is a macro with a _null **pointer** constant_ and should not be assigned to an integer. A null pointer value is not guaranteed to have a representation or conversion value of _all bits zero_. "NUL" otoh is not a format part of the statndard, it is just trhe ASCII name of a character code with all bits zero. In C it is not "an invisible character" (that depends on the character set and glyph mapped to this position. In fact it makes an array a string in C. C does not have a string type.

Comment: NUL is a byte size zero.   It occupies a byte size zero.

Comment: @Nguaial: Please provide a reference to the standard where it even mentions a symbol/macro/etc `NUL`. And it does not mean "noting, but is an ASCII code like "CR", "LF", etc. In C a _null character_  has a very special meaning, which is definitively not "nothing"!

Comment: @nguai - i still don't understand what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: @EvilTeach - Which part you are not clear?

Comment: Nul is a byte size zero.