# Difficulty understanding linked list implementation (the struct part)?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

```
struct node
{ 
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*start;
```

I don't understand what `struct node *next` does, I know it points to the address of the next variable; but how as in implementation? Is `node *next` similar to `struct node *next`?

And what about the `*start` is it similar to `struct node *start`?

I am finding very difficulty understanding linked lists implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand what `struct node *next` does, I know it points to the address of the next variable; ...

This is correct.

> ... but how as in implementation ?

The implementation is pretty much exactly how you described the behaviour: A pointer is implemented as an object whose value is the memory address of the pointed object.

> Is `node *next` similar to `struct node *next`?

Not only similar, but pretty much identical.<sup>†</sup>

---

> And what about the `*start` is it similar to `struct node *start`?

It **is** `struct node *start`. See the complete declaration:

```
struct node /* structure definition */ *start;
```

It is a combined declaration of a variable, and definition of a structure.

---

† The `struct` keyword is just used to disambiguate that the following identifier is in the name space<sup>††</sup> of structure tags. In your case it is redundant, because there are no non-structure identifier `Node` to disambiguate, and in C++ structure tags are also type names.

What you're probably looking at is C code, where the name space<sup>††</sup> specifier is mandatory for structure tags.

†† In this context, I refer to C name spaces, not C++ name spaces.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.Helped me alot

Answer (score 2):

> And what about the `*start` is it similar to `struct node *start`?

If you define a struct and put a name after it you declare a variable of that struct.
Here you declare your `start` variable which is of the type `node*` (pointer to node). So the variable named `start` is your first node.

> I don't understand what `struct node *next` does, I know it points to the address of the next variable; but how as in implementation?

Your list holds the `data as int` and the `address of the next` node as you said before.

In an implementation of that list you would allocate memory for each new node and put the address of that node into the `next` member of the struct. For more understanding of linked lists I would look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Therefore I would recommend to write functions for inserting, deleting, etc.

If you work with lists object orientation might be helpful. But take your time to understand more and more complicated code.

Comment: Thanks brother.Helped me a lot.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept one of the given answers or ask for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

A node needs to be pointing to next node. So it has a pointer variable named `next`. Since next is also a node struct you declare it as `struct node *next;`. `start` is your first node.

Comment: Can  i write node *next instead of struct node *next?

Answer (score 1):

Your code really looks like a piece of C, not C++ code. In C++ you would presumably never write your own list implementation, but use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). If you do, it would look like

```
class list
{
  struct node
  {
    type data;          // type could be a template parameter
    node*next=nullptr;  // set next to null by default
  };
  node*head=nullptr;    // list is empty by default
public:
  /* ... */
};
```

In particular, the `struct` keyword in `struct node*next;` is not necessary and the `start` pointer can be declared on a separate line for clarity.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me the difference between NULL and nullptr ?

Comment: [`NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) is a C macro and should be avoided in C++. C++ has the keyword [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) that should be used instead.