# Relation between calloc char array and null terminating character

Tags: c, calloc, strncpy, nul

This whole "debate" on the web about `strncpy` being safe vs unsafe is driving me crazy. I find some people saying `strncpy` is the "devil", which to me sounds like they lack the programming discipline. I get that there is no `\0` character added to the end of `dest` when the `src` is greater than the `dest` (which ultimately causes problems). I've heard of `strlcpy`, but from what I gather it's not standard. I want my code to be as portable as possible, so I don't consider this a viable solution.

Here is my current solution...

First define the buffer size

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024
```

Within the program, allocate the buffer using `calloc`

```
char *buffer;

buffer = calloc(BUFSIZE+1, sizeof(char));
```

Then later in the code, lets say I want to copy `msg` to `buffer` and I use

```
strncpy(buffer,msg,BUFSIZE);
```

Since I preallocated `buffer` with `BUFSIZE + 1` then this ensures that the last byte of `buffer` is `\0` regardless if `msg` is greater than `BUFSIZE`.

Now the question is, does `calloc` initialize the character array with `\0`? Is it wrong to interpret the zero allocation of `calloc` to be the same as `\0`?

Comment: From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/: "Allocate and zero-initialize array".  `\0` just means "the character represented by the integer 0".

Comment: in this case `calloc` is useless as you change the value of your string completely just use `malloc`.

Comment: I believe I'm only changing the first `BUFSIZE` elements of the string. The point of `calloc` (with BUFSIZE+1) was to ensure the last element is `0`, from which I gather in the solution is equal to `\0`. This means the string will always have a nul terminating character. `malloc` does not initialize the array with zeros, hence why I didn't use it.

Comment: Or you could use `malloc` and assign the only `\0` that matters.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the array to `0` will fill all characters to `\0`.

> So '\0' is completely equivalent to an unadorned 0 integer constant - the only difference is in the intent that it conveys to a human reader ("I'm using this as a null character.").

See [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)