# Getting warning message when trying to initialize "employee" struct

Tags: c

Getting the following warning message:

```
database.c:15:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  ptr->LastName[0] = NULL;
                   ^
database.c:16:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  ptr->FirstMiddleName[0] = NULL;

                      ^
```

I tried using pointers a few different ways but I don't understand them very well and can't figure out how to avoid this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        struct employee {
                char LastName[30];
                char FirstMiddleName[35];
                float Salary;
                int YearHired;
        };

        struct employee employees[20];
        struct employee *ptr, person;
        ptr = &person;

        ptr->LastName[0] = NULL;
        ptr->FirstMiddleName[0] = NULL;
        ptr->Salary = -1;
        ptr->YearHired = -1;

        printf("%i", person.YearHired);
        printf("%s", person.LastName[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                employees[i] = person;
                //printf("%i\n", i);
        }

        printf("%c", employees[3].LastName[0]);
}
```

I would like to initialize an array of 20 "employees" with the initial values such that numerical values are set to -1, and the strings contain the null character as the zeroth character.
Instead I get the above warning, and if I replace the NULL assignment with a letter it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is a null pointer constant, not the null character. Use:

```
ptr->LastName[0] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler warning message is clear enough to tell what you are doing the wrong. Here

```
ptr->LastName[0]  = NULL; /* NULL is equivalent of (void*)0 not \0 */
```

`LastName[0]` is `character` not *character pointer*. You might want

```
ptr->LastName[0]  = '\0'; /* now here \0 and Lastname[0] both are of char type */
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a pointer constant, and you're trying to assign that to an element of the `LastName` or `FirstMiddleName` fields.  Instead, assign 0 to the first character of each, which makes them empty strings.

```
    ptr->LastName[0] = 0;
    ptr->FirstMiddleName[0] = 0;
```

This also isn't valid:

```
printf("%s", person.LastName[0]);
```

Because `person.LastName[0]` is a single character, not a string.  You instead want:

```
printf("%s", person.LastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the warning replace NULL with the null character '\0'.  NULL is a pointer, not what you want.

```
ptr->LastName[0] = '\0';
```

To fix the segmentation fault replace **person.LastName[0]** with **person.LastName** in your printf.  **person.LastName[0]** is a single character.  printf %s expects the address of a null-terminated string.

```
printf("%s", person.LastName);
```

That printf statement may still fail if you don't put a null termination somewhere in your string:

```
 ptr->LastName[0] = 'a';   //may still fail in printf without termination.
```

vs

```
ptr->LastName[0] = 'a';   
ptr->LastName[1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro NULL is an invalid pointer not the ASCII NUL character, you should not use it as a character constant.  The NUL character is `\0`:

```
    ptr->LastName[0] = `\0` ;
    ptr->FirstMiddleName[0] = `\0` ;
```

Or it is also valid to simply use a literal zero:

```
    ptr->LastName[0] = 0 ;
    ptr->FirstMiddleName[0] = 0 ;
```