# String having the value of Null

Tags: c, error-handling

Firstly i will show an example:

```
void main(void){
char word[12];
char input[12];
int i;
printf("Input some word: ");
scanf("%s",input);

for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)
    word[i]=NULL;

if(word[i]==NULL){
        printf(" %c ",word[i]);
    }

}
```

As you can see i give to word[i] a NULL value that makes the warning "Warning assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast", then the next warning  is in the if "Warning comparison between pointer and integer".
So how can i resolve this warnings, exist other options instead of giving the NULL value?

Comment: `word[i]` (for every valid `i`) is a `char`; `NULL` is not a `char` and (in your implementation) is not compatible so you get the warnings. Use `'\0'` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Okay it works thank you very much. by the way i am new here do i need to do something to the post after the problem is solved?

Comment: If you like one of the answers below, mark it as accepted. You can also mark several as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both '\0' and NULL have value 0.
The difference is the intent & more-human-readable code.

To learn more, refer to: [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

It has excellent explanations with examples.

Answer (score 2):

string null terminator is `'\0'`, `NULL` is usually for pointers.