# Socket programming: What is causing select() system call not return on current thread execution?

Tags: c++, macos, sockets

I am having problem with [select()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/select.2.html) call on an multi-socket app.

Here is how it is supposed to work.

Writer writes: `[0010]HelloWorld` on a socket, where the the first 4 character are always digits representing the payload size.

Reader should do the following:

1. call `select()` to verify if a given socket is readable, then `read` first 4 character, change char to digit to get size of buffer in number, and allocate a buffer of that size.
2. copy characters (after the first 4 characters) from the socket and paste to the buffer for further processing
3. `read` 4 characters again, which should fail and upon failure to read any data, the app should clean exit the program.

Problem is in the 3rd `select` call. `select` followed by `read` iteration, every time we check `select()` for readability of socket and once that is verified, we proceed with the `read`. While the socket is valid and almost whole process works just fine, except for last point at step 3 before `read` is expected to fail, I call `select()` system call for last time, and it completely freezes the thread upon calling `select` .

I am not finding any sources online which can explain this weird phenomenon. To verify that the thread is not returning I have created a dummy object just before making the system call `select()` and logged it on destruction. Unformtunately, the distructor is never getting called.

Source code is propriotery, cannot be shared.

snippet:

```
fd_set f_set;
int err = 0;
while(check_edge_case())
{
  if(time_out_valid())
  {
     int nfds = GetFileDescriptor();

     FD_ZERO(&f_set);
     FD_SET(nfds, &f_set);

     for_each (clients, [&](client_t &client)
     {
       int fd = client.descriptor;
       if(fd)
       {
         FD_SET(fd, &f_set);
         nfds = std::max(nfds, fd);
       }
     });
    
    ++nfds;
    
    // perform select
    if(time_out_valid())
    {
      struct timeval_t time_val = GetTimeOut();
      err = select(nfds, &f_set, 0,0, &time_val);
    }
    else
    {
      err = select(nfds, &f_set, 0, 0, 0); // blocks in this statement
    }
    
    // check for error
    if(!err)
    {
      err = 0;
      continue;
    }
    else if (err = -1 && errno == EINTR)
    {
      err = 0;
      continue;
    }
    else if (err < 0)
    {
      retunr errno;
    }
    
    if(FD_ISSET(GetFileDescriptor(), &f_set))
    {
      return ECANCELED;
    }
    
    // further processing for read operation
    bool executed = false;
    for_each (clients, [&](client_t &client)
     {
       int fd = client.descriptor;
       if(FD_ISSET(fd, &f_set))
       {
         if(client.f_read) err = client.f_read();
         else err = 0;
         
         executed = true;
         break;
       }
     });
    
    if(!found) return ENODATA;
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never had a similar experience with `select`. Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure. Let me edit the post and update it in a while.

Comment: "freezing".. or blocking? Are you sure there's data available to read and you're correctly resetting the read list before every call? Are you using a timeout? `select` will block if none of its file descriptor lists can perform non-blocking ops and there's no timeout. Sounds like a strange architecture to me that you're relying on a failed `select` call for proper app operation.

Comment: @yano It looks like blocking should be a correct term here. There is not data available to read in the 3rd iteration. I am setting the read list correctly, because in the 1st and 2nd iteration the read works fine, following the same loop, in the same thread. Is `select` supposed to block when no data available?

Comment: yes, `select` will block if it has no work to do. You can give it a timeout (eg, "wait for this long before giving up") if you don't want it to block indefinitely. Read the [`select` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). `select` will block indefinitely if there's no timeout and no file descriptor ready for ops. If there is a timeout, it will block for approximately that long before returning. The `timeout` section has more details.

Comment: Without code, we can only speculate. Shooting in the dark I can only speculate that on read reads the content of two writes which leave the third read with nothing left to read.

Comment: You may want to re-think your design/architecture, particularly if using TCP. My typical `select` usage has been `while(running){ ... select(.../*some small millisecond timeout*/); }`, and if I want to exit cleanly, I set `running=false` somewhere else. Depending on exactly 2 successful `select` reads doesn't sound particularly robust, especially for TCP which can deliver data to you in any sized chunks. But, if that's how things work, you might as well quit after the 2nd successful `select` read, no point in calling it a 3rd time if there's nothing to read.

Comment: @doron updated with code snippet

Comment: @TedLyngmo Updated with code snippet.

Comment: @yano, it makes sense, but the problem it that it is a thrid-party lib code which I am using in my code. I can take a look and play around with the time out logic as for now, I have using `select(nfds, &f_set, 0, 0, 0);` 0 timeout, which should return immidiately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the infinite `select` blockage. I was not `close`ing the socket after processing.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong `timeout` parameter to your second call to `select`, which is therefore blocking.

From the documentation:

> If both fields of the `timeval` structure are zero, `then select()` returns immediately.
> (This is useful for polling.)

> If `timeout` is specified as `NULL`, `select()` blocks indefinitely waiting for a file descriptor to become ready.

So pass the address of a zeroed `timeval` struct, rather than `0`, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

@PaulSanders gave the correct answer, just thought I'd explain it a little more.  Your `select(nfds, &f_set, 0, 0, 0);` call is passing a 0 for the `timespec` argument.  This is ***not*** the same thing as a zeroed out `timespec`.  The fifth argument of `select` is a *pointer* to a `timespec`, so when you put 0 there, it's read as a `NULL` pointer constant, equivalent to a `NULL` pointer (you can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)).  As the man page says, if the `timeout` is `NULL` (that is, the address of a valid `timespec` is *not* passed in), then `select` will block indefinitely, and this is the behavior you're seeing.  I would change that code to

```
// perform select
struct timeval_t time_val = { 0 }; // zeros the time values in the struct
if(time_out_valid())
{
  // whatever this does to retrieve the timeout, presumably it's
  // returning a non-zeroed struct
  time_val = GetTimeOut();
}
// the address of `time_val` is _not_ 0/NULL. It is valid.
// If `time_out_valid() is false, then its data fields `tv_sec` and
// `tv_nsec` are still both 0, and `select` will return immediately.
err = select(nfds, &f_set, 0, 0, &time_val);
```

This is IMHO, but as a practice, I always use `NULL` for NULL/invalid pointers, and `0` for actual zero values (for `int`s, for instance).  That just makes it clearer to me, at a glance, what data types are being used/expected.  However, I've seen plenty of C code that uses 0 for NULL/invalid pointers, so that's hardly a "best practice rule".  But, with that in mind, I would change your `select` call to

```
err = select(nfds, &f_set, NULL, NULL, &time_val);
```

I see you're tagged c++.  If you're using modern c++, you can probably do

```
err = select(nfds, &f_set, nullptr, nullptr, &time_val);
```

as the preferred method, but I have not tested this.