# How do I initialize all elements of TrieNodes' children to null

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie, construction

I am trying to solve a Trie problem, for which I create a `TrieNode` class as below:

```cpp
class TrieNode {
    public:
    bool isWord;
    TrieNode* children[26];
    TrieNode() {
        isWord=false;
        memset(children, NULL, sizeof(children));    //results in warning
    };
};
```

This results in a warning:

> warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 2 of 'void* memset(void*, int, size_t)' [-Wconversion-null]

Replacing it with `nullptr` results in a compile time error:

> error: cannot convert 'std::nullptr_t' to 'int' for argument '2' to 'void* memset(void*, int, size_t)'

So my question is, how do I initialize all the values in `children` to `NULL`/`nullptr`?  I tried a few options such as `children[26]={ nullptr };`, but those all resulted in runtime errors (worked fine only with `memset(children, NULL, sizeof(children));`).

Eventually, while building the trie, I wish to have the following logic:

```cpp
if(!curr->children[index]) {
    curr->children[index]=new TrieNode();
}
curr=curr->children[index];
```

Comment: `children[26]={ nullptr };` sets the 27th element, but there are only 26 elements!

Comment: Also, things would be a lot easier if you used `std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>`. It has a default constructor. You could even use `std::map<char, TrieNode>` but that's a bit cheating (since the map itself uses a red-black tree)

Comment: @MSalters Simpler? No, though the seeming safety-net is often appreciated. The owner should really have a custom dtor linearizing the trie and deleting in a loop, without any recursion. Unless a very limited depth is actually guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do:

```
class TrieNode
{
public:
    bool isWord = false;
    TrieNode* children[26]{};

    TrieNode() = default;
};
```

Comment: Simplifying even more: `struct TrieNode { bool isWord {}; TrieNode* children[26]{}; };` Or considering it is value-initialized, one could also remove the in-class initializers...

Comment: @Deduplicator: That simplification changes also the "semantic" though, as aggregate initialization can occurs...

Comment: Considering how it seems to be used, that doesn't seem to matter. Still, I should have thought of it...

Comment: @Jarod42, could you please explain it?  I don't follow what `TrieNode() = default;` does.  If it value initializes the elements, then why do we need to set `isWord` to `false` explicitly?  If it doesn't, then why don't we have to set each element of `children` to `nullptr`?

Comment: @Someone: `children` defaults to `{}`. Since that has less than 26 elements (in fact, zero), the "remaining" 26 elements are set to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Someone: [Default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) `TrieNode() = default;` will [default construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) their members, and not do [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). so build-in types such as `bool` or array of pointer need initialization. `TrieNode* children[26]{}` set each pointer to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest C++ option is `std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), nullptr)`.

Comment: Ah, I had tried this one, but I used `NULL` instead of `nullptr` and it result in compile time error.

Comment: `NULL` is a MACRO which might be `0` (so deduced as `int`) or `((void*)0)` (deduced as `void*`) which are problematic for assignment.

Comment: @Jarod42: Incorrect, `void*` is not a valid type. `NULL` could be `nullptr` - deduced as `nullptr_t` - in which case it would have worked, but from the failure we can deduce that `NULL` was defined on that compiler as integral zero.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to bypass the problem is passing 0 in place of NULL,
since second parameter suppose to be a integer as per function prototype.

`memset(children, 0, sizeof(children));`

Refer to this in case confusion with 0 vs NULL:
[What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Comment: The linked answer is for C, which is another language.