# Understanding why output of C++ code is different in terminal and output file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, char

I knew that global int initalised array have default value 0, so I tried to see what default value a char array would have

```
char arr[10];
int main() {
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

using this code I found output as
<0x00> 10 times each in new line in the light text, i.e NUL, as expected by me, in console of sublime text
(printing in terminal just gave 10 blank lines)

But then I tried to write the output to a file using  `freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);`
and to my surprise output changed to

```
000d 0a00 0d0a 000d 0a00 0d0a 000d 0a00
0d0a 000d 0a00 0d0a 000d 0a00 0d0a
```

also on removing endl output was

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

further adding `' '` in place of endl gave 10 spaces only

I am unable to understand what's going on I expected zeros to be printed in all these cases, what's different in writing to a file to printing on terminal?

I looked up [difference between NUL, NULL and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) but still the output of these codes are not clear to me.

Can someone please help me to understand the reasoning?
Thanks!

Comment: The `0x0d0a` pair is a carriage return and linefeed. You don't see the actual characters in the terminal but you do see the effect otherwise everything would be printed on a single line.

Comment: *I expected zeros to be printed in all these cases*  And just why would you expect that?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks, I think got first and second case, 00 is 8 bit representation of NUL, and 0d0a is for carriage return and linefeed, also is there any reason for space after word size other than reading clarity? Also, I still didn't get why only 10 spaces when replaced with ' ' why not 00 printed in that case?

Comment: That might just be your (hex) editor trying to show things nicely and can be turned off I guess.