# Can I use a pointer as the condition of a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

In the below code a pointer (`ptr`) is used as the condition of a while loop. Can you tell me how that loop is working?

```
struct Node* ptr = head;
while (ptr)
{
    printf("%d -> ", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
printf("null\n");
```

Comment: The loop will continue until ptr is null.

Comment: It just keeps looping until the `ptr` is NULL. Starts off with the `head` pointer as current and moves to the `next` pointer on each iteration until the current pointer is NULL. In C, NULL is 0 and 0 is false.

Comment: It basically checks every time whether that pointer points to something and not NULL. If it does, it executes the while loop code.

Comment: This is a very standard walk of a linked list (whether singly or doubly linked doesn't matter). You _might) more often see this with a for loop (especially in C++ where the initializer can be a full declarative statement) but it still works fine.

Comment: A pointer is just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c there is no boolean type but Zero is interpreted as false and anything non-zero is interpreted as true.

for example this if body will be executed

```c
if (3) { printf("true"); }
```

also in C `NULL` is a constants with value 0 as `(void *)` type

so in your loop any if `ptr` is null the condition will be like `while (0)` so it will stop the loop

You loop will check the current node if it null it will stop, else it will point to the next node

Check this useful answer also for more information:
[What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)